# I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax while using %precision 2

Tags: python

I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax when using the following commands:

```
>>> import csv

>>> %precision 2
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

does anyone one know why?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use [IPython magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision) in a regular interpreter.

Comment: I am taking an online course in Coursera and this is the beginning of an example where you export excel files to work with the data

Comment: Daniel Roseman do you know how to fix that?

Comment: As Jon says, this syntax is from IPython. The online course almost certainly has told you to use that.

Comment: do we have an equivalent for python 3.7?

Comment: @Sara It's not a matter of Python version you are using; it's which *implementation* you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, `%precision 2` is not a native python syntax. It's a special functionality provided by [IPython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html).

Check out [IPython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html), it's really useful for learning. For installing [IPython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html), just do `pip install ipython` or check out [this page](https://ipython.org/install.html).

Go ahead and read [precision-handling-python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/precision-handling-python/) and [stackoverflow-ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439753/set-global-output-precision-python) for better understanding.