# Change significant figures reporting for default floats

Tags: python, numpy

Is there anyway to set the "default" number of significant figures for python floats or numpy floats?

I hate wrapping the 100+ print statements I have with custom rounding code, that sucks.

Comment: Instead of changing the default printing style, you could replace the `print` function with your custom version that handles floats differently.

Comment: Print controls for Python floats and numpy arrays are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways to approach the problem.

1. You can write a definition where you will pass your output statements and round the numbers to floating points you need in your definition.
2. As mentioned in the comment above by  GZ0 and answered here
   [Set global output precision python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439753/set-global-output-precision-python)

   you can change your print function

> def print(*args):
> **builtins**.print(*("%.2f" % a if isinstance(a, float) else a
> for a in args))